# Google Sheets Apps Script - How to add an Arrayformula and multiple associated IF functions within a script (Without showing the formula within UI)

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I was wondering if someone is able to assist?

I'm trying to add an Arrayformula consisting of two IF functions, so I'm wanting to merge the following two formulas into one cell:

1. =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D13:D104="","",(IF(K13:K104,K13:K104*20,"$0"))))
2. =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D105:D="","",(IF(K105:K,K105:K*C4,"$0"))))

So the first section of the sheet needs to be multiplied by 20, and then the figure has changed and needs to be multiplied by 25 (which is cell C4)

1. Is it possible to merge these into one cell containing an Arrayformula+the two IF functions (or is there another/easier way for this)
2. Is it possible to add this into Google Apps Script so that it works in the backend (so not just a script that applies the formula into a cell - but doesn't show in the frontend or sheet)
3. More of a general question - When using Arrayformula with IF; and for example the output is specific text e.g. "Test Complete" associated to the range F2:F (checking if E2:E contains a particular phrase e.g. "Done") - for the empty cells in between (due to setting the False outcome as "") is it possible to somehow randomly add data into these blank cells without interrupting the formula? (so I have to option for automated text if the cell to the left states a particular term/word, but still have the option to manually add random data into blank cells)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As for 1st and 2nd questions: it looks like a task for a custom function. Something like this:

```
function MULTI() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var value = sheet.getRange('K'+row).getValue();
  return (row < 105) ? value * 20 : value * 25;
}
```

It gets a value from column K and multiplies it by 20 if the row less than 105 and by 25 for the rest of rows.

[image]

Here is the variant of the same formula that uses the cell 'C4':

```
function MULTIC4() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var value = sheet.getRange('K'+row).getValue();
  var c4 = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();
  return (row < 105) ? value * 20 : value * c4;
}
```

And it can be done with the trigger `onEdit()`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col != 11) return; // 11 = K

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Sheet1') return;

  var c4 = sheet.getRange('C4').getValue();
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  var dest_cell = sheet.getRange('D'+row);
  var value = sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue();
  var result = (row < 105) ? value * 20 : value * c4;
  dest_cell.setValue(result);
}
```

It recalculates automatically the value in the cell of column 'D' (current row) every time when you're changing value in the cell of column 'K'. On the sheet 'Sheet1'.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thanks @Yuri Khristich

By any chance would you know how to combine this into an 'Arrayformula' (for the frontend of the sheet)?

Tried both of your suggestions and they work perfect, but because the related cells contain data that was added via a formula, the script doesn't recognise the input as 'edit', so I think  it's probably going to just be easier to use a formula within the cell.

I've tried various combinations IF + IFS, but for some reason I just can't get it to work.

Also, I've learned quite a lot from your response, so thank you very much.

Comment: Alas, I have no enough knowledge about array formulas, and I don't like them, because they look extremely ugly :). I don't even know if it (to change an output based on a row number, I suppose) is possible in array formula. So It's need another guy to help you.